# How to debug activity startup after destroy?

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

I want to debug such events as restoring previously activity state after user navigates away (for example back or home) from an activity and then returns back. Normally, activity (and the whole app) is not destroyed by Android between these 2 events. But there are some cases when activity is destroyed that results in uncatched exception on activity restoring (because of unsaved fields, for example). I want to debug such moments step by step.

I was able to tune Android system such way, that it destroys every activity when user leaves it (thanks to custom android build in VMware). But when activity is destroyed, Eclipse debug session is also terminated and when user navigates back to the activity - I do not have any access to the debugger.

The question is how can I receive access to the debugger and my breakpoints in various places like onDialogPrepare(), onCrete() and so on?

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is finished and onDestroy() is called, then the next time you open that activity it will be entirely re-created. So you could just debug the onCreate method!

Comment: Not exactly. Android tries to restore activity state, in particular it recreates dialogs, that were open when user pressed HOME button. But if activity is created first time this doesn't happens. At least such behavior I see now.

Comment: Android tries to restore state only when the Activity has not been fully destroyed. Please take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: I can even make some video capture of this behavior, if needed :)

Comment: Can you provide a cite from docs? The provided picture doesn't show  onRestoreInstanceState() and other related stuff. I mean, yes activity is created from scratch, but doings do not end on this.

Comment: of course! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: From your url: `The default implementation of this method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).` But this doesn't contradicts what I said before. But according to you it will not restore saved state in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), am I wright?

Comment: also from onDestroy() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) description: Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Comment: The main words are: `...or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space`. So activity can be fully destroyed and then recreated by system.

Comment: then I don't know how to debug this... sorry